# How do you code in Unreal Engine "increase the value of 2 variables by a constant, unless either of them is zero"?

Tags: unreal-engine4

How do you code an  algorithm to "increase the value of 2 variables by a constant, unless either of them is zero"?

Comment: Hi, what you are asking is extremely basic and games development is not for beginners, it takes a lot of knowledge and work. This site isn't a place where other people will do the work for you either. I suggest you to start with some basic programming tutorials first.

Comment: @Crasher nice gathekeeping. C++ in unreal my be a frustrating experience for beginners. But blueprints are far quicker to get going with and there’s plenty of other environments great for or even meant for beginners with no experience (scratch, gamemaker, construct etc…). Some of them are also great for people that don’t care about coding and Judy want to make games.